# autofill of 4 different fields from 1 SMS with a code in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page for code verification, in it I use 4 text fields with 1 character. When one field is filled, the focus moves to another field. But there is one problem when I log in through iOS, when I enter the code, I see an SMS with a code. And when I type in the code, only one column with the first number is filled. The rest are not. How can I fix it so that when I click 1 the number is in the first field 2 - in the second and so on.

```html
return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                          return Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                _buildCodeCell(
                                  tc1,
                                  error,
                                  f1,
                                  next: f2,
                                  previous: null,
                                ),
                                _buildCodeCell(
                                  tc2,
                                  error,
                                  f2,
                                  next: f3,
                                  previous: f1,
                                ),
                                _buildCodeCell(
                                  tc3,
                                  error,
                                  f3,
                                  next: f4,
                                  previous: f2,
                                ),
                                _buildCodeCell(
                                  tc4,
                                  error,
                                  f4,
                                  next: null,
                                  previous: f3,
                                ),
                              ]);
                        });
```

[image]

Comment: this package will help https://pub.dev/packages/otp_autofill

Comment: @AhmedElsarag thank you, but it's a bit wrong, I only get the code (without words)

Comment: if you get code from end point ask backed to send custom message